# What linguistic key terms are necessary to be understood in order to understand the idea behind discourse analysis?

Tags: terminology, theoretical-linguistics, discourse-analysis

I was asked to get an understanding for what discourse analysis is. As for now, this terms has no meaning to me at all, I've tried to read about the concept in different off-and online encyclopedias, but I only stumbled across further key terms i had to knew in advance, once I've looked for the new key term, further key terms emerged, so my conclusion is, that to understand the concept of discourse analysis i have to understand many key terms in advance which are connected in a tree-like structure with unknown depth.

Could you provide in this thread key terms and key ideas that are indispensable on the road to discourse analysis.

Comment: First of all read a textbook in general linguistics.

Comment: What is the purpose of stackexchange than, every question could be discovered in a textbook.

Comment: Not every. Since you're asking a question in linguistics, you should know at least the basic linguistic terminology, because you won't be able to understand the answers here, and you seem to have problems even with the basics. Reading more on general linguistics will help you substantially.

Comment: Please [edit] this and fix all your typos.

Comment: i ve a very basic understanding of linguistics asking for furhter basic understanding of linguistics. if you told me that argument in a forum on quantuum mechanics, i would agree, you really need a good understanding of the basics, but this is smurfing language "science" - a playground for idiots like us not einsteins.

Comment: @meireikei You will received upvotes when you show research effort and downvotes if you don't. Not doing any research before asking a question here won't mean that your question will be closed or deleted, but it might not be well received. The more you can do to present a high quality question the better for everyone.

Comment: @meireikei: "than" is used to compare two adjectives. "Then" is used for sequence of events and cause and effect.

Comment: Read the following book:
``O'grady, O. W., Archibald, J., Aronoff, M., & Rees-Miller, J. (1989). Contemporary linguistics: An introduction.``

Answer (score 1):

For lists of the linguistic terms with their short explanation see these links:

- [General linguistics terms](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~sam/teach/IntroGenLing/terms.html) - terms are grouped according to the field of linguistics, downloadable variant available.
- [Small glossary of linguistics](https://www.uni-due.de/ELE/LinguisticGlossary.html) -  terms are grouped according to the field of linguistics.
- [Glossary of linguistic terms](http://webspace.qmul.ac.uk/cjpountain/linggloss.htm) -  terms are listed alphabetically.

Also see [this answer](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/388/2689) on our Linguistics Meta SE.